# How do I change the datetime format from ( 'y-m-d' ) to ( 'd m y' )

Tags: wpdb, date

I have code that finds the date a page was last updated:

```
<?php global $wpdb; $psm_mod_datetime = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_modified FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = 'Current Chapter Volunteer Openings'");
echo("Updated:  " . substr($psm_mod_datetime, 0, 10));
?>
```

which prints **Updated: 2021-09-05** after the page title. I need it to print **Updated: 05 September 2021**

How do I change the format for the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with Wordpress, just some PHP code to get what you're after.

You need to convert MySQL datetime to Unix time by using:

`$timestamp = strtotime($psm_mod_datetime);`

Then you output this timestamp in the format you desire by using:

`echo "Updated: ".date('d F Y', $timestamp);`